# "I built" VS "I was able to build"

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

The sentence in my cover letter is:

> I was able to build positive customer relationships by answering calls promptly and maintaining a friendly attitude.

"built" sounds less passive than "able to build" but is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that "built" sounds more active.  And yes, it is grammatically correct:

> I **built** positive customer relationships by answering calls promptly and maintaining a friendly attitude.

Built is the appropriate past-tense form of "to build", and it's perfectly valid to say that you built relationships.